# changing a dojo datagrids structure dynamically

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am having trouble attempting to change the structure of a datagrid after new information is received. I need to be able to change the number of columns everytime a query is made.

The javascript code I use to create the grid

```
function setgrid(){
    var gridLayout = [];
    var key, i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        key = i + "";
        gridLayout.push({
            field: key, 
            name: key,
            editable: false
        });                       
    }

    // create a new grid:
    billsGrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        query: {},
        //store: store,
        clientSort: true,
        rowSelector: '20px',
        structure: gridLayout,
        columnReordering: true
    }, gridContainer);

    // Call startup, in order to render the grid:
    billsGrid.startup();
}
```

and the html:

```
<div id="gridContainer" style="width: 650px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid silver;" />
```

How would I change the grid to have a new layout of say 5 columns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it, just needed to know what to call to apply a new layout to the existing grid. In this case: 
`billsGrid.setStructure(newLayout);`

Comment: Does this affect the entire grid or only the following rows?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of dojo, there is no method `setStructure`. You might want to use:

```
grid.set('structure', newStructure);
```